# Why are these tsconfig paths not working?

Tags: typescript, alias, tsconfig, typescript2.9

I'm trying to do something very similar to the [jquery path example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in the documentation, but TS keeps throwing `TS2307` (webpack compiles fine):

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
        "@client": [
            "client",
        ],
        "@suir": [
            "../node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs", // not working
        ],
    },
    // …
},
"include": [
    "*.d.ts",
    "client/**/*",
    "../node_modules/semantic-ui-react", // is this necessary?
],
```

Changing `baseUrl` to `"."` and updating `includes` and `paths` makes no difference (`@client` continues to work and `@suir` continues to not work).

Changing `"@suir"` to `"@suir/"` or `"@suir/*"` (and appending `/*` to its value) also makes no difference.

---

The reason I'm doing this is to simplify my imports (I'm specifying them explicitly instead of pulling named exports from the bundle in order to reduce my vendor bundle size—saves about 1 MB):

```
import Button from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/elements/Button'; // works

import Button from '@suir/elements/Button'; // not found
```

Comment: Just wanted to add to this. For me, `paths` stop working when i use the `files` property in tsconfig.json. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I have no idea why this is now working on the eleventh time I tried (yet didn't the first 10), but the `/*` seems to be the secret sauce, and the example in the docs is apparently pointing to a specific file (and the file extension is omitted).

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src", // setting a value for baseUrl is required
        "moduleResolution": "node", // was not set before, but is the default
        "paths": {
            "@client/*": [
                "client/*",
            ],
            "@suir/*": [ // notice the `/*` at the end
                "../node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/*", // notice the `/*`
            ],
        },
        // …
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/client/**/*",
    ],
}
```

Comment: For anyone else still having the problem even though having `/*` make sure your `baseUrl` is set, as I just spent hours trying to fix this.

Comment: please edit this post and add what @ErraticFox said about the baseUrl. Thank you!

Comment: In case anyone is using VSCode and having trouble getting the `/*` solution to work. Try Cmd+Shift+P > Typescript: Restart TS Server.

Comment: @ErraticFox still not working with base url as "./'

Comment: thanks @EmilyZhai it did the trick for me!

Comment: it worked! but still got absolutely no idea why

Comment: this worked for me! pretty confused why so many examples online omit the `/*`. maybe they're all using webpack?

Comment: @ErraticFox 'As of TypeScript 4.1, baseUrl is no longer required to be set when using paths’ https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl

Comment: per @HynekS answer on this question, its best to have baseUrl as   "."   everything is relative to the project folder not src folder (as per this answer)

Answer (score 82):

As mentioned in the comments by [Emily Zhai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6727389/emily-zhai), this can sometimes just require a language server restart.

In VSCode, you can press `Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + P` and search for `Typescript: Restart TS Server`.

After restarting, everything started working for me.

Comment: Note that you might need to be in a .ts file for that option to appear. (I had to be focused on a .ts file.)

Comment: Restart worked for me using Webstorm - thanks!

Comment: Thank you so so much!!  Without this answer I don't know how much more time I would had spent surfing the web to solve this!

Comment: @DarkCrazy :) It has bitten me multiple times. So many hours wasted on what was just a simple restart

Comment: `Typescript: Restart TS Server` <- this should be in every tutorial that ever mentions adjusting baseUrl or paths..

Answer (score 78):

I did also struggle with `.tsconfig` not recognizing my aliases (while in another project that supposed to have the save config it worked perfectly).

As it turned out, it was a rookie mistake: I put the `paths` prop to the end of the JSON object, but it has to be a nested property of the `compilerOptions` part:

```json
// This does't work ❌
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
     //...
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "twin.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
}
```

```json
// This should work ✅
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
     //...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "twin.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

Comment: Man! you are a lifesaver! I literally spent 2 days just on this small mistake!

Comment: Glad I could help. I think it's quite counter-intuitive, considering `"include"` and `"exclude"` (which are also relative paths) being placed in the object root.

Comment: Omg, I was looking for this for 3 hours already, I was going nuts

Comment: This in combination with the `/*` magic at the end for BOTH the ALIAS ( @components **`/*`** )itself and the path made things work, except images - for those I had to add custom typing files as described here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57129153/1835470 basically you create a special file in `typings/custom/import-yourextension.d.ts` in your project root

Comment: Thank you, worked for me! Luckily I found this SO article rather quickly. Interesting: This worked before with Angular 9. With updating to Angular 12, I got Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve .... Now it's ok again !

Comment: Than you, worked for me.

Comment: @HynekS THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! If you had a coffee button I'd gladly buy you one because MAN! lol

Comment: @Jamiel Unfortunately, I dont' have one yet.. :) Glad I could help.

Comment: @HynekS paths supposed to be in compilerOptions. How does the first code even get allowed by the IDE?

Comment: Spent a whole day just to see this the next day, damn, thanks man!

Answer (score 42):

Out of the box, it doesn't work with tsc or ts-node.
But with some packages (tsc-alias & module-alias), it works.
No babel or webpack setup are required.

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["common/*"],
      "@services/*": ["services/*"],
    },
    ...
  },
}
```

### Working with TSC

Add **tsc-alias** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias) as dev dependency

```
yarn add --dev tsc-alias
```

And add it to your build command

```
"build": "tsc && tsc-alias",
```

### Working with TS-NODE

Add **module-alias** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) dependency

```
yarn add module-alias
```

Create a file referencing all aliases

```
// src/paths.ts

import 'module-alias/register';
import { addAliases } from 'module-alias';

addAliases({
  '@common': `${__dirname}/common`,
  '@services': `${__dirname}/services`,
});
```

And import it in your entry script as first import

```
// src/server.ts

import './paths';
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
...

const app = express();
...
app.listen(port, onListen(port));
```

Comment: just to mention, for `module-alias` might be required to install types also:  `npm i --save-dev @types/module-alias`

Comment: Wow! I though tsc would work out of the box! Thank you for clarifing

Comment: You can also add `NODE_PATH=outDir` before `node start`

Comment: Thanks so much. Was about to pull my hair out.

Comment: Thank you! This answer needs to get bumped higher!

Answer (score 34):

This might help someone - if you use `tsc` or a tool to compile your TS code to a separate folder such as `dist`, `tsconfig-paths` register does *NOT* work out the box. I have a tsconfig.json like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "jsx": "react",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
        "rootDir": ".",
        "paths": {
            "shared/*": ["./shared/*"],
        }
    },
    "include": ["./client/**/*", "./server/**/*"]
}
```

You can see that a path such as `shared/someFolder/someScript` will resolve correctly to the `shared` folder in my project, which is a load cleaner than lots of relative `../../../../` paths.

However, this was throwing me the error:

```
➜  game git:(game-dev) ✗ node --inspect -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/server/runProd.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/f69956aa-d8d6-4f39-8be1-9c3e8383d4be
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'shared/types/UserTypes'
```

I did a bit of digging and found that the `tryPaths` array produced by tsconfig-paths has absolute URLs relative to the `project`/cwd base, rather than the build `dist` folder.

[image: inspect screengrab]

This seems obvious in retrospect. There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to handle this with the library, so I have solved this by copying the `tsconfig.json` into the `dist` folder and running `node -r tsconfig-paths/register main.js`.

Comment: Great explanation! Relevant Github issue: https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths/issues/75

Answer (score 10):

After some trial and error, I got to know that, it works differently than we think.

```
//tsconfig.json
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@components/": ["src/components/"],
}

//SomeCompomonent.tsx
import { Button } from "@components/" // will work
import Button from "@components/Button" // will not work
```

to make the second import line work you need to put `*`

```
//tsconfig.json
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
}

//SomeCompomonent.tsx
import { Button } from "@components/" // will not work
import Button from "@components/Button" // will work
```

To make both work

```
//tsconfig.json
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@components/": ["src/components/"],
  "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
}

//SomeCompomonent.tsx
import { Button } from "@components/" // will work
import Button from "@components/Button" // will work
```

Comment: Thankssss! this worked for me 'cause I use named imports :D

Comment: This helped out big time!!! thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Like, pkestikar said, [tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) can help with that. Save it on devDependencies with `yarn add --dev tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` , add the following configuration on `next.config.js`

```
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: "./tsconfig.json" })]
  }
}
```

My paths started to work with that. Here's my `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    },
}
```

And here is the import of a component.

`import { Button } from '@/components/Button/Button'`

It works with just `import { Button } from 'components/Button/Button'` as well.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Vite, you should install [vite-tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths).

```
npm i vite-tsconfig-paths --save-dev
```

Then, inject `vite-tsconfig-paths` using the `vite.config.ts` module

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
})
```

You may need to restart Vite and/or your TS server after making these changes.

Comment: if this is not working check https://stackoverflow.com/a/74719153/7668448. `v4.0.0` have a bug. `v4.0.1` fix it. Install with `npm install vite-tsconfig-paths@latest`

Comment: Of all the solutions above, this is the one that worked for me with Vite.

Answer (score 7):

While trying to make tsconfig work, the following command proved very helpful:

```
npx tsc --showConfig
```

This will output some json with the `files` field showing the actual recognized files by your configuration.

Comment: What am I meant to see here if paths are working?

Answer (score 4):

Even if the base url is set check if it's on the default value "./"
then should be changed to "src", only that way worked for me.

Comment: Strange, but it works. I can confirm that. This advice saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

If someone still has this issue even after doing everything mentioned. Try close down VS code and reopen again, that worked for me 2 hours after looking around..

Comment: I had it working before, and numerous reloads didn't work. Complete close & reopen did!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Webpack` with `ts-loader` and it's still not working after trying all of the answers above, you might need to use a plugin in the resolve section of your `Webpack` config file - [tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin); so it follows the paths you've put in in your `tsconfig.json` file while compiling.

Source - https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#baseurl--paths-module-resolution

Answer (score 1):

Try add in tsConfig.json the follow property inside CompileOptions:

"baseUrl": "."

In my case working.

Answer (score 1):

## Check your workspace

**Check how you have opened your workspace** in VScode.

In my case, I have this structure:

```
├── my-proyect
│   ├── client* (this is my react folder)
│   └── server
```

To make it work, I have o open the **client** folder. If I open the whole project it doesn't work.

**Other things to check:**

1. tsconfig.json should be something like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
    }
  },
}
```

2. vite.config.ts should be something like this (if you use vite)

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
})
```

Restart TS Server.

```
In VSCode, you can press **Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + P** and search for Typescript:
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution for me 

Answer (score 1):

In my case, even though I set baseUrl in the parent config, I had to set baseUrl again in the derived config to make VSCode happy and successfully resolve the configured paths
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to use babel to compile the code

```
npm i -D @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-typescript babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

Then on the build command

```
"build": "babel src --extensions \".js,.ts\" --out-dir dist --copy-files --no-copy-ignored"
```

And the babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
presets: [
    [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
            targets: {
                node: 'current'
            }
        }
    ],
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
],
plugins: [
    ['module-resolver', {
        alias: {
            '@config': './src/config',
            '@modules': './src/modules',
            '@shared': './src/shared'
        }
    }]
],
ignore: [
    '**/*.spec.ts'
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that I was adding path to the wrong file. If you are working on a big project where you are not sure of it's configurations, chances are that the config file be extended by other files. In my project there was another file called `tsconfig.app.json`, notice the extend attribute in the very first row:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*",
      ],
      "@app/*": ["app/*"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend, do not change ***tsconfig.json*** rather create ***tconfig.app.json*** and add following content
If already exists then simply add paths, you can reuse your *shortPath*

Note: its json file so check comma (,) and don't miss or keep extras like in **.ts* files

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@chat/*": ["@app/chat/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["@app/shared/*"],
      "@auth/*": ["@app/auth/*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of [Emily Zhai's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50888885/5104886), if someone wants to **Restart TypeScript/ESLint Servers Automatically** when configs changed on VS Code, my extension may help

[Auto Restart TypeScript / ESLint Servers - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neotan.vscode-auto-restart-typescript-eslint-servers)

Answer (score 0):

for parcel with react add `compilerOptions.paths` and add [`parcel-resolver-tspaths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-resolver-tspaths) to resolvers for `.parcelrc`(create if not present) file.
or checkout Offical: https://parceljs.org/plugin-browser/?type=%22resolver%22&page=0&filter=%22resolver-path%22&includeOfficial=true

```
npm install --save-dev parcel-resolver-tspaths
```

##### package.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["./src/app/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"]
    },
  }
  ...
}
```

##### .parcelrc

```json
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "resolvers": [
    "...",
    "parcel-resolver-tspaths"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Javascript files, also check that in your `tsconfig.json` you have

```
 "allowJs": true
```

otherwise TypeScript will ignore .js and .jsx files imports

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the path provided is correct. It will throw error "module and its decrations not found".

Answer (score -3):

For myself, after much trial and error the solution was simple. Remove this line from my tsconfig and it worked.

```
"extends": [
    "plugin:import/recommended",
]
```

and

```
"rules": {
    "import/no-unresolved": "error",,
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution and just removes the error. If the project is compiling without errors and eslint is still showing an error, then there is a misconfiguration in the eslint config.