# TS2307: Cannot find module './images/logo.png'

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to import a local png image into my ts webpack project, and I get the following error.

```
TS2307: Cannot find module './images/logo.png'.
```

All my other modules are importing just fine, ie; my css, svg and ts files. It only seems to happen with png.

My webpack.config.js modules section

```
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts$/,
      use:['ts-loader']
    },{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    },{
      test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
      use: ['url-loader?limit=100000']
    },{
      test: /\.png$/,
      use: ['file-loader']
    }]
  }
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ES2015.Promise", "ES5"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true
  }
}
```

My import statement

```
import Logo from './images/logo.png';
```

My file structure

```
root
-src
--css
--images
---logo.png
--index.ts
--templates.ts
-package.json
-tsconfig.json
-webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript image import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100401/typescript-image-import)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59139251/9349388 This solution worked for me. The issue I faced was the same.

Answer (score 71):

I found the answer here. [Webpack & Typescript image import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638454/webpack-typescript-image-import?rq=1)

Here's what I did.

Added a new directory and a import-png.d.ts file

```
root
-typings
--custom
---import-png.d.ts
```

import-png.d.ts

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

changed my file-loader module to this:

```
{
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|jp2|webp)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: 'images/[name].[ext]'
      }
```

and now I can import with a statement like this:

```
import Logo from './images/logo.png'
```

Comment: PS, ```value``` should be ```string```.

Comment: I'm telling you custom type declarations in projectroot/custom/import-* that is some dark magic ...  adding the files there for each jpg&png was enough :-)

Answer (score 17):

My mistake was that I excluded the reference react-app-env.d.ts:

```
/* eslint-disable spaced-comment */
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
```

Eslint has pushed me to do this because of the spaced-comment rule.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: For those who are trying to use this approach. You would also need `react-scripts` development package for it to work: `npm install react-scripts --save-dev`. `react-app-env.d.ts` file can be placed anywhere where it can be seen by TypeScript compiler, the usual location is `src` directory of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in the images directory with the name `images.d.ts` and paste the below code.

```
declare module "*.png" {

   export default value : any;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

Just create a d.ts file in root folder and copy below line.

```
 declare module '*'
```

Restart the VScode, Good to go

Comment: This is a terrible idea, you will lose any intellisense on trying to import from modules that do not exist.