# React Images Import in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, import

I've set my own react project with typescript and react and my own webpack config. Hence I did or did not something somewhere wrong and I can't figure out what.

My problem is that I can't import my images.

I've tried the solutions from those guides but to no avail: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-display-images-in-react-dfe22a66d5e7

My setup is as follows:

src > assets/components/theme index.tsx custom.d.ts

assets > img > Logo.png

components > different folders for components & App.tsx

Index.tsx and custom.d.ts are next to each other.

In my webpack config I have this:

```
{
   test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
   type: 'asset/resource',
}
```

In my custom.d.ts file I have this:

```
declare module '*.jpg'
declare module '*.png'
declare module '*.jpeg'
declare module '*.gif'
```

I am trying to import the file like this: `import Logo from '../../assets/img/Logo'`

I am getting this error: Cannot find module `'../../assets/img/Logo'` or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [TS2307: Cannot find module './images/logo.png'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127606/ts2307-cannot-find-module-images-logo-png) and [Typescript image import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100401/typescript-image-import)

Answer (score 1):

You have `asset/resource` in your config, but said your structure is `assets/img`, try changing `asset` to `assets`in your config, or creating the path `asset/resource`.

Comment: maybe change `resource` to `img` too.