# Typescript: Intellisense cannot find absolute path when using imports

Tags: typescript, import, path

I am having problems regarding VS Code autocompletion and warning messages (red wiggly lines). Intellisense is giving me false warning when specifying absolute path for imports in typescript files. I am using Tauri and Svelte as framework.

I have made these simple files for debugging the problem:

`src/my_app.ts`:

```
import { my_value } from "@folder/my_test_file"
```

`src/my/test/folder/my_test_file.ts`:

```
export let my_value = 8;
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    /**
     * Typecheck JS in `.svelte` and `.js` files by default.
     * Disable checkJs if you'd like to use dynamic types in JS.
     * Note that setting allowJs false does not prevent the use
     * of JS in `.svelte` files.
     */
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {

      "@folder/*": [
        "src/my/test/folder/*"
      ],

      "@src/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },

  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.{svelte,ts,js}"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

My directory:

[image]

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "piping-system-solver",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
    "tauri": "tauri"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^1.0.0-next.30",
    "@tauri-apps/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.13",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^2.0.1",
    "svelte": "^3.44.0",
    "svelte-check": "^2.2.7",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.9.8",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tauri-apps/api": "^1.0.0-rc.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "split-grid": "^1.0.11",
    "svelte-drag-and-drop-actions": "^1.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

The version of following extensions:

- Svelte for VS Code: v106.1.0
- TypeScript Hero: v3.0.0

In the file `src/my_app.ts` (and similarily in all my other .ts files), typescript keeps alerting the following warning over the line of code above:

```
"Cannot find module '@folder/my_test_file' or its corresponding type declarations."
```

...eventhough the code compiles and works. This also affects code completion when typing absolute paths. Though when specifying absolute paths within my .svelte files, this warning does not appear, and code completion works.

Here's an list of all mentionable trials, thoughts and observations:

1. Relative paths works, both compiling and Intellisenses suggestions.
2. All svelte files work flawlessly by specifying absolute paths (`import { my_value } from "@folder/my_test_file"` gives no error in .svelte files, and Intellisense suggest subfolders).
3. I've tried "Restart TS Server", but it does not help.
4. I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679031/tsconfig-paths-not-working) which has alot of suggestions on how to solve this, but none of them works for me.
5. I have installed Typescript Hero.
6. I have installed vite-tsconfig-paths from [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths)
7. I've observed that Intellisense warnings and suggestions updates dynamically according to changes in the tsconfig.ts file, while the actual program only updates when closing- and reopening the window (npm run tauri dev).
8. Specifying absolute paths works in .svelte files, even if you remove the `"paths"` configuration in tsconfig.json, leaving no path aliases. It works by starting with `"src"` (example: `"src/some/path/file"`). Seems like the path alias `"src"` is built into svelte?
9. (new) I've noticed now, that in .svelte files, more things are being suggested when starting double quotes (.js files, .ts files, .json files, among them also folders), whilst in my .ts files, only modules are being suggested (image in front of suggestion according to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)).

I'm also eager to know, if this could be a bug in Tauri, Svelte og Typescript.

Comment: If the knowledgeable people in the community dont know what could be wrong, please let me know, so i can lay this problem aside for now, and maybe try fix this later.

Comment: did you try changing `"@folder/*": ["src/my/test/folder/*"],` to `"@folder/*": ["./src/my/test/folder/*"],`

Comment: @nullptr, your suggested change does not affect the result. This means, the code compiles and work, but the error warning still appears.

Comment: weird. I just set this up yesterday for a project(react, ts, vite). [this](https://0x0.st/oVYD.paths.js) is my  `compilerOptions.paths`

Comment: for the sake of completeness, what are the currently installed versions of each of the tools you are using?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the insalled versions of tools by displaying the "package.json" file. I'm not 100% sure if those are all the tools of interest in debugging this, so if theres something missing, please specify what, and i'll inform it as soon at possible. I also added the version of "TypeScript Hero" and "Svelte for VS Code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. Seems to be issue with your configuration. Steps to make work:

1. Add "src/*.ts" to `include` array in `tsconfig.json`.
2. Add an alias to vite.config.ts: `'@folder/': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/my/test/folder/', import.meta.url))` (alternatively you can install [vite-tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths) plugin and add to you vite.config.ts which does this step for you, based on the content of your tsconfig).

I.e. `vite.config.ts` should look like:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '@folder/': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/my/test/folder/', import.meta.url))
    },
  },
});
```

Minimal working example project with the `tsconfig.json` and `package.json` you provided: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xg6eei?file=README.md. Note I can't rule out something else being up with your local configuration (typescript project config is complex) but you can work backwards from the above linked example working project config.

Comment: Amazing, works flawlessly, so this gets marked at solved! Forever grateful! I cannot understand how i have not found anything on the web mentioning this simple missing addition! For your answer however, the auto correct seems to work only by adding "src/*.ts" to the 'include' array in 'tsconfig.json'. The change in 'vite.config.ts' is not necessary. I dont why this could be...

Comment: Glad it worked for you. The change in the vite.config.ts is not needed for vscode intellisense part, but your build (npm run build) will fail without it. typescript intellisense doesn't really check this part for you or complain about it because it relies on the runtime module loader.

Comment: That's wierd, because the code has been compiling fine all the time, it's just intellisense that haven't been working properly. Could it be the plugin 'vite-tsconfig-paths' that has only got the code working, but not made paths working for intellisense?

Comment: I want to point out, after continuing coding for a while, that the path alias registration of intellisense feels unstable. Sometimes it works, sometimes it don't, but for most of the time it works, which does not make it a real problem. I don't think it's random, and without being a 100% sure, it feels like intellisense path alias is not working for a short while just after a file has been created or deleted. Maybe someone can relate to my experience so far?

Comment: Oh, yes your correct, ts-config-paths essentially does step two for you. Better to use that. I didn't notice you we're using it because you didn't paste your vite.config.ts, but now see it there in your package.json. Updated answer.

Comment: Wow this is minimal repo is great. I don’t use Vite, but it was lean enough for me to figure out my own monorepo issue. The imports aren’t relying on package.json at all.