# tsconfig paths not importing css modules, only js/ts files

Tags: javascript, import, path, tsconfig

I used [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) to scaffold a typescript-react project, and i wanted to use the given `tsconfig.json` file to create shortcuts for my directories, so i wont have to deal with long relative paths when importing stuff in my components.

This is `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@styles/*": ["styles/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["routes/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

I get an error when trying to import `LandingPage.module.css` into my component `LandingPage.tsx` using this line : `import styles from "@styles/LandingPage.module.css";`

here's the relevant folder structure :

[image: folder structure]

The Intellisense in VS Code when i type `import styles from "@styles/"` shows only the js file in `styles` folder, and doesn't pick up on the css module.

### Attempted solution :

A comment about restarting the Typescript server, didn't work.

Ref : [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679031/tsconfig-paths-not-working)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm also seeing it in a current project, VSCode 1.82.0. Same type of setup, I have a path in my `tsconfig.json` that looks like: `"@/*": ["./src/*"]`, and my import in a `tsx` file referencing `'@/styles/Home.module.css'` (which exists) fails with "Cannot find module..."

I've done the similar types of things, restarted the TS language server, etc. and the error persists.